# Why do I get directed to grub screen instead of booting completely?

Tags: 12.04, resolution, reboot, grub-efi

I am a new user of Ubuntu and only recently have had problems with booting. It either fails to recognize my monitor or sends me directly to a grub screen rather than booting completely. This is my grub file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=efi"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1200x60
```

I'm curious about the `reboot=efi`. In my research, I've seen that they are not included in other codes. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info). This will help us understand your problem.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1118652/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "reboot=efi" is for when something fails. As for your grub menu if you change that line where it says

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

You won't get a grub menu anymore. As for your resolution issues I am very good at dealing with and would love to assist with that also if you need.

Very Respectfully,

Matthew Kaulfers

Comment: thanks for the tip--I'll try it.  As for resolution, I have a View Sonic VP2330wb.  It is an older monitor, but I have a brand new dvi cable I'm using.  Since this problem has started, once I get Ubuntu loaded, the resolution is really bad, and when I go to display settings, it says I have a laptop screen (I'm not using multiple monitors) and won't let me use a resolution higher than 1024x768.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 is not recommended as you would be (nearly) blocked in case of problem with a kernel update. Better leave 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: Okay, that is good to go--just fixed that.